# the gifs are not looping

Tags: java, loops, animated-gif

I am creating a little game and I have a problem. I putted 2 gifs and when the gif finish, the image stops and don't loop. I want a way to loop this gif because out of the program it works well.
This is the code:

```
import java.io.File;

  import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
  import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JLabel;
  import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
  import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

  public class EjemploJLayeredPane {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame v = new JFrame("Ejemplo de JLayeredPane");
        JLayeredPane layered = new JLayeredPane();


        JLabel fondo = new JLabel();
        ImageIcon imagen = new ImageIcon("fondo batalla.png");
        fondo.setIcon(imagen);
        fondo.setSize(imagen.getIconWidth(), imagen.getIconHeight());


        JLabel primerPlano1 = new JLabel();
        ImageIcon imagen1 = new ImageIcon("pikachufrente.gif");
        primerPlano1.setIcon(imagen1);
        primerPlano1.setBounds(275,-80,400,400);


        JLabel primerPlano2 = new JLabel();
        ImageIcon imagen2 = new ImageIcon("charmanderespalda.gif");
        primerPlano2.setIcon(imagen2);
        primerPlano2.setBounds(85,20,400,400);


        layered.add(fondo, new Integer(1));
        layered.add(primerPlano1, new Integer(2));
        layered.add(primerPlano2, new Integer(2));


        v.getContentPane().add(layered);
        v.setSize(imagen.getIconWidth(), imagen.getIconHeight() + 20);
        v.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        v.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: It works for me.  The fact that we're seeing inconsistent behavior suggests the problem is your execution of Swing operations outside of the AWT event dispatch thread, which is documented to cause unpredictable behavior.  Move all of your code into the `run` method of a Runnable and pass that Runnable to [EventQueue.invokeLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me - no bounds no nothing:

```
  JFrame f=new JFrame();
  f.setSize(500, 500);
  JLabel l=new JLabel();
  ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon("bird.gif");
  l.setIcon(icon);
  f.add(l);
  f.setVisible(true);
```